# Does "old" literally mean "old" in this context, or is it an intensifier?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Haven't I told you he's not going?" he hissed. "He's
> going to Stonewall High and he'll be grateful for it. I've read those
> letters and he needs all sorts of rubbish –– spell books and wands and
> ––" 
>        "If he wants ter go, a great Muggle like you
> won't stop him," growled Hagrid. "Stop Lily an' James Potter's son
> goin' ter Hogwarts! Yer mad. His name's been down ever since he was
> born. He's off ter the finest school of witchcraft and wizardry in the
> world. Seven years there and he won't know himself. He'll be with
> youngsters of his own sort, fer a change, an' he'll be under the
> greatest headmaster Hogwarts ever had Albus Dumbled––"
>
> "I AM NOT PAYING FOR SOME CRACKPOT ***OLD*** FOOL TO
> TEACH HIM MAGIC TRICKS!" yelled Uncle Vernon. (Harry Potter and the
> Sorcerer's Stone)

*Old* is used as an intensifier, say these websites: [Webster's #5](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/old); [Wiktionary #12](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old). So I guess the example's *old* has the meaning after an adjective crackpot. But I’m not sure, ‘cause the websites seem to kind of restrict the boundary of the use. Can *old* be used as an intensifier after all sorts of adjectives or adjective phrases?

Comment: I think in this case he really does mean old- he's referring to Dumbledore who is an old wizard.

Comment: @Jim, However, Mr. Dursley ought not have leaned about the headmaster Albus Dumbledore. For the school is not known to so called Muggle’s world, and so he couldn’t have known whether Dumbledore is old or kind of young person.

Comment: The Muggles in general don't know about it but Vernon and Petunia know about it and even  though they try very hard to ignore it, they know that Lily went there, and if you notice, Vernon cuts Hagrid off right in the middle of saying *Dumbledore* by calling Hagrid's "greatest headmaster Hogwarts ever had" a "crackpot old fool"

Comment: I think you can argue for the other interpretation, but to me the literal meaning of *old* is the most natural one here.  The other use has a connotation of familiarity which seems to me to be possibly inappropriate in this case.

Comment: One thing, I would specifically like to know, how on earth can you enjoy the story if you think so thoroughly about grammar, meaning, pronunciation or anything else you ask here about? :-O

Comment: @Mistu4u thoughts are mutual. +1 "Old" here is being really "old" and said to Dumbledore for sure.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer, Apparently at least it seems so. :-)

Comment: @Mistu4u For some of us, grammar itself is highly enjoyable, and contributes to our enjoyment of the narrative. In any case, you cannot even read the narrative, much less enjoy it, until you master the grammar.

Comment: @StoneyB, Yeah, I agree that if the reader does not know the basic grammar and meaning, he can't enjoy the story for the lack of understandability, however this particular reader is IMHO way above basic grammar, although I don't deny the fact sometimes the questions are quite interesting and sometimes they are the result of reading too much deep into something (_like this one IMO_).

Comment: @Mistu4u I have to say that Listenever constantly makes me stop and think, and I'm a fairly competent reader. This question has me stumped for the time being. And let's remember, she asks these questions so she can get more enjoyment out of *all the English books she reads for the rest of her life*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think old has a literal meaning.

This [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old) seems closest.

> c :  of long standing

In other words the person has been a fool for a very long time, long enough to prove that that's all he'll ever be.